# How to implement Socket connection in Watch OS 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io, watchos-3

In one of my application we are implementing live stock market update using socket connection and we have implemented it using in iOS app using [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift). But we also developing same app in Watch OS 3.0.
But compiler not able to deal with classes of `Core Network` prefixed with `CF`as like (`CFHTTPMessage`) with error of type `CFHTTPMessage undeclared type`.

So can any one implemented socket connection on Watch OS 3.0 ?

Is there any other way to accomplish same functionality on Watch OS ?

Is it fine to implement socket connection on Watch independently or we are going wrong way?

I have came across one watch app([Stock Tracker : Real Time Stock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stocks-tracker-real-time-stock-forex-and-chart/id517166254?mt=8)) with stock update which working independently without iOS App in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple watch cannot do any network requests itself, everything is done via IPhone using Watch Connectivity framework to send and receive data: https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity

Apple watch is quite limited for now, as far as I know even though it was a wifi capabilities, they are not for developers. Those things are battery draining and as it's the major problem for Watch persistent connections (like sockets) are restricted.

Comment: Agree with you.But https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stocks-tracker-real-time-stock-forex-and-chart/id517166254?mt=8 , this app updating real time data without launching of iOS App. 

Thanks

Comment: I bet they're just polling data regularly

Comment: can we poll data from parent app without launching app? iOS app is not in background though data is updating.

Comment: yes you can make network requests from watch (which will go via phone). It's like any other app (Apple Stocks, Messenger and so on) updates data without iPhone app in fore/back ground.

Comment: OK, Thanks. We will look in it.